# Как вставить свою вёрстку на страницу определённой категории Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Я хочу на каждой странице категории товаров выводить своё описание. Да, это можно сделать стандартными средствами - в поле Описание внести нужный текст и выводить на страницах категорий это описание. Но мне нужно, кроме просто текста, ещё много чего сверстать/вывести...Пробовал через условие (в файле archive-product.php):

```
    if (is_category('19')) {
        //мой код
    }
```

Но ничего не выводит. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу.

Comment: Должно работать. Если не работает - не там/не так делаешь. Только это вариант... не очень мягко говоря. Не нужно так делать. И да, надеюсь ты не прямо в плагине правил? Какая используется тема? Дочку сделал?

Answer (score 0):

Вместо is_category использовал is_product_category и всё заработало.
Вопрос решен.